# How to retrieve cell data in Telerik RadGridView from a GridViewCellBase

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik

I am using Telerik for WPF's control RadGridView and I am using the following code to obtain the GridViewCellBase object of the specific cell I want:

```
var rows = rdgTeamItems.ChildrenOfType<GridViewRow>();
GridViewRow row = rows.ElementAt(2);
var cell = (from c in row.Cells
         where c.Column.Header.ToString().Equals("Description")
         select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

How can I get and set the data in this specific column?